# Do you really answer "How do you do?" with "How do you do?"

Tags: greetings, questions

We're told in our English classes (learning English as a foreign language) that the only possible answer to

> - How do you do?

is to repeat the question:

> - How do you do?

(While it's perfectly OK to answer other similar questions

> - How are you? / How are you doing?
> - Fine, thanks / etc

)

That said, then I talk to English speakers with Skype or in chats, I tried to ask the question, but the answer was never "how do you do?". It was rather "fine. you?" or something.

What is right and what is a myth?

Comment: Nobody in America uses "How do you do?" In _My Fair Lady_, Liza is taught the most exaggerated version of this phrase!

Comment: @ash it's also used in "Boy Named Sue" for the rhyming effect: "And I said: 'My name is Sue, how do you do?'"

Comment: I'm not a native English speaker but I'm amazed that a simple greeting can motive such interesting discussion!

Comment: @rmartinsjr - In your comment, "motive" will be perhaps "motivate".

Comment: You're right @DineshKumarGarg! I don't know how I could make this mistake, perhaps autocorrect played a trick on me...

Comment: This is one of those expressions that defines your social class, or to channel Nancy Mitford, whether one is U or non-U. The formality traditionally taught in TEFL classes is rather dated and now only used by those who have little to do with social classes beneath their own self-perceived position.

Comment: I suppose the non-question form might arguably be shown as "How do you do." not "How do you do?" in print in these days of enlightened use of punctuation. It's often further from a true question than a rhetorical question is, and polite requests for instance are dropping the question mark (eg "Pass the salt, would you, Aubrey.")

Comment: [Britannica](https://www.britannica.com/dictionary/eb/qa/What-do-you-do-How-do-you-do-#:~:text=%22How%20do%20you%20do%22%20is,and%20follow%20us%20on%20Twitter!) ('Ask the Editor') at least hints that the question mark is an unnecessary relict. And [Dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/how-do-you-do) seems to license the dropping. The contraction 'Howdy' never has the question mark, of course.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

As Cerberus wrote about ['U' English](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/U_and_non-U_English), replying to "How do you do" with "How do you do" used to be the case among some classes in England (at least), but it seems to be (sadly) nearly extinct. Kate Fox writes in the first chapter of *Watching the English* (which is about talking about the weather):

> We used to have another option, at least for some social situations, but the ‘How do you do?’ greeting (to which the apparently ludicrous correct response is to repeat the question back ‘How do you do?’) is now regarded by many as somewhat archaic, and is no longer the universal standard greeting. The ‘Nice day, isn’t it?’ exchange must, however, be understood in the same light, and not taken literally: ‘How do you do?’ is not a real question about health or well-being, and ‘Nice day, isn’t it?’ is not a real question about the weather.

So in this usage, "How do you do?" wasn't an actual question about the person: it was just a meaningless greeting, and for instance what one might say when introduced to someone (in lieu of "Pleased to meet you"), presumably while tipping one's hat. In reply, the other person, also wishing to make the same meaningless greeting, would say "How do you do".
Note that "How do you do" in this usage was even spoken as a statement, not as a question (i.e., without a rising tone at the end).

These days "How do you do?" is more likely to be interpreted as an actual question. Interestingly, as n0nChun observes, one does sometimes hear a similar exchange these days, with "What's up" getting the reply "What's up", or even just "sup" — "sup".

Comment: This is somewhat similar to how the correct English response to "Sorry" (when someone bumps into you, say) is "Sorry". :-)

Comment: @ShreevatsaR Last week ad Edinburgh airport, someone ran into me, I said "`Sorry`" and he said "`My fault`" as an excuse.

Comment: You could also say it this way: "how do you do" back has been replaced with an equally meaningless reply. It is just an exterior change of convention; etiquette demands that you give only one answer when asked about your well-being in somewhat formal situations: you are doing well, thank you. At "not so great", your interlocutor would be forced to ask "oh dear, why not?", and you'd be forced to talk about your problems, which was not at all what you had in mind on this visit to your fiancée's grandmother. Asking about a good friend's health is and has always been something else entirely.

Comment: Kate Fox is bang on the money as usual!

Comment: how should I answer ‘Nice day, isn’t it?’?

Comment: @valya: Kate Fox has an entire chapter on how to answer "Nice day, isn't it?", but the main point is that you should agree (mumbling "mmm yes, isn't it?" is fine), whatever you think about the weather. It's better to remain silent and be slightly rude (it's rude but okay not to talk to strangers), than to disagree and say "no the weather is rather unpleasant" which is more rude. :-)

Comment: It's certainly not meaningless, in the same way "Hello" isn't meaningless. / I guess "Nice day, isn't it?" is before my time, but I'd expect it as a genuine question (albeit smalltalk), and would consider silence ruder than (polite) disagreement: "Well, it's a bit too hot for my liking".

Comment: @Hugo: What I meant is that it's meaningless, in the same way that "Hello" is meaningless: it just means it's a greeting, nothing more (and certainly not the literal meaning). (I think the fact that you think it's a genuine question about the other person, and expect the same about "nice day" and the like, goes with my *"These days "How do you do?" is more likely to be interpreted as an actual question."* in the last paragraph!)

Comment: @ShreevatsaR: Greetings are full of meaning, you can infer quite a bit from the choice (or not) and delivery. (If I heard "How do you do?" (I can't remember the last time), I know that's not a literal question, but to me "Nice day, isn't it?" sounds like a real question to be answered, although not necessarily one for serious, prolonged debate.)

Comment: @Hugo: That's exactly my point; the meaning is in the greeting, mode of delivery, tone of voice and all that; there's no intended meaning in the phrase itself. The greeting could have been "aah eel pst boo" and if that were the conventional greeting, all the implicit meaning from body language / tone of voice etc. would still be carried when delivered, even though you'd agree (I think) that the phrase itself was meaningless. It's not so bad in the case of "How do you do", but that's the sort of thing I meant -- that the literal meaning of the words had much less importance (close to none).

Comment: I would say that it survives in a contracted form: "Howdy" is a common, acceptable response to itself.

Comment: In Russian all schools teach us "How do you do" and say that it's a formal way of saying "Hello" in <London that is the capital of Great Britain>.

Answer (score 29):

The reason for the varied responses is that the question you ask is not *only* about the English language, but it also touches on etiquette, which is more idiomatic.

The short answer is: yes, the answer to "How do you do?" is "How do you do?"  It is also acceptable to reply "I'm fine, and you?" and similar variations.

However -- and this is important to the etiquette side of things and not so much the language side -- "how do you do?" is actually **not** a question!  It is a greeting, similar to "good morning" and, hence, an appropriate reply is also "good morning to you!"

Etiquette allows simple replies such as "I'm fine, how are you?" to appease the literalists who might feel off-put by a non-reply to what they mis-interpret as having asked you a question.  However, good manners also prevents one from discussing their personal troubles with every acquaintance or stranger on the street who greets them with "good morning!" or "how do you do?"  Hence, any reply in the form of an answer is *always* "I'm fine" (followed by "and you?", as a courtesy), and never "terrible!  My stomach hurts and I have a splitting headache!"

Of course, if you are talking with a friend who truly inquires about  your wellbeing, and you feel like sharing with them, by all means, do so.  My answer is not meant to prevent that, only to allow you the dignity of a polite answer for passers-by that does not require you to spill your guts.

Good luck!

Answer (score 12):

I believe this rule only applies to [U English](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/U_and_non-U_English) nowadays. It was probably more widespread in the past. As far as I know, it is still de rigueur in certain circles; that is, when someone asks *how do you do*, you say it back; but it will now rarely be asked any more, and so the occasion for saying it back won't arise either. Perhaps this shibboleth does not extend to America; I wonder how U and non-U language work there, as I am sure they must exist in some form in nearly every culture.

I have spoken with some foreigners here who were specifically taught U Dutch and kept wondering why most people used different words. I think language learners should at least be explained the difference before being taught one variant or the other, both of which can be equally useful—that is, if their teacher is good.

Answer (score 11):

Many of my non-native-English-speaking friends have also said they were taught the same as you, but with the same principle applying to all similar greetings -- "How's it going?", "How are you?", et al.

I find that bizarre. As an American English speaker, I am always taken by surprise if someone answers my "how do you do?" with another "how do you do?". While I don't always care much about their response, I do feel that I am actually asking a question to open up conversation via responses like, "Actually I just came down with a cold," or, "Great! My school application was accepted today!".

I agree with you, I expect a real response, even if it's, "Fine, you?" 90% of the time.

Comment: There *is* a difference noted in proper/formal manners wherein you respond with "How do you do?" I have no idea how I learned that but *something* taught me that this was the Proper way to greet someone. If I remember correctly, they even made a few jokes about it in My Fair Lady.

Comment: Really? What part of the United States are you from? I have never heard another American say "How do you do?" nor would I expect a stranger to actually answer the question with anything more than "Fine, you?"

Comment: @HaL: I grew up in the midwest, went to university in Boston, and lived in Seattle for 6 years. I have probably never greeted with literally, "How do you do?" but I was lumping all these similar greetings into one. I don't think I greet strangers this way. Like I said, for me, it's not about the specific answer as much as it's opening up the conversation.

Comment: See my answer, separately.  There are 2 issues here: English language and etiquette.  My reference for the etiquette part is Miss Manners, but I'm pretty sure that Post and others agree on this issue.

Comment: I'd add that "howdy" is a contraction of "how do you do", which IS said in parts of the Midwest where I grew up. And "howdy" is definitely never understood as a question.

Comment: I had this dilemma for years while learning English where we had a dialog in English with its sentence-by-sentence translation, and part of the dialog was an exchange of two "How do you do**?**"s, and the translations were something like "Glad to meet you**.**" Asking the exact question as this one, I was mocked by my aggressive teacher and the rest of the class. Still can't see how no-one never noticed that punctuation change and never questioned why the translation of a question sentence turns out to be an affirmative!

Answer (score 5):

As a native UK English speaker, I'd be very surprised to hear "How do you do?" used in a modern conversation in London. It's somewhat archaic. However "How do you do?" would be an appropriate response - the phrase should be interpreted more like "hello" than an actual question.

"How are you doing?" is now much more common, and would typically be answered with a neutral response and a similar question back - e.g. "I'm fine thanks, and how are you?". I would consider it mildly impolite not to answer the question at all, but you can answer any way you like - it's meant to be taken as a genuine question.

Answer (score 3):

Agree with most of the guys, yet I've heard `What's up!` always replied with a `What's Up!`, more like a `Hello!` I think.

Comment: Please keep "I agree", "you're right" and other "me, too" type responses to comments, rather than posting them as answers.  Thanks!

Comment: And why? It's not that my answer doesn't add value to the discussion.

Comment: The comments are for discussion. Answers are supposed to be answers.

Answer (score 3):

Myth.  In England, "How do you do?" although replaced mainly with the likes of "Alright?" and "What's up?" is just about surviving in some parts under the guise of "'ow do?".  Like most greetings, can be:

- just repeated back.
- answered with any other greeting (even "How do you do?", why not!).
- answered literally.
- responded to visually (nod/smile/salute).
- safely ignored if the asker doesn't seem to be waiting around for a reply, but consider getting your greeting in first the next time. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

While questions of the type you list there are frequently either partially or fully rhetorical (in that the asker doesn't actually care how you are, but rather is simply following the social convention to ask), I've never heard of any sort of rule or custom of *only* answering the question with another question.

Certainly, it's possible to simply respond with the question you were asked, especially if you're passing someone rather than actually beginning a conversation.  But I would suggest that a more standard response would be of the sort you got on chat.  A one word answer followed by asking about you as well.

Answer (score 2):

There is no rule that says the correct answer to "how do you do?" is to reply back the same question.

In my experience, most people would reply back with "I am fine" without to give any further detail, even in the case they are not actually feeling well.
I have also heard people who, receiving back "I am fine; and you?" as answer, didn't answer back.

Most people would not take attention to the reply given, but replying to a question with another question could be interpreted differently from the person who first asked the question.

Answer (score 2):

Another modern UK version is "alright?", "alright".  The reply can be a statement or the same ritual question repeated back, which is rather neat.

Comment: Or the French "ça va?", "ça va".

Comment: @ShreevastaR, which in full renderers as: "ça va?", "ça va, ça va?", "ça va." :)

Comment: Although "Are you alright?"/"You alright?"/"alright?" rarely requires any sort of reply. This was rather confusing during my first year in the UK, when you stopped to answer the question while the other person already passed by.

Comment: I find the BE/AE difference here interesting. To my understanding, "Alright"(BE) and "Whats up"/"Wassup"(AE) have the meaning of a general greeting like "Hello". "What's up?"(BE) and "Alright?"(AE) have the same meaning too, but are more likely to be understood as an enquiry, and when said to a stranger might elicit a response such as, "Nothing, why?"

Answer (score 0):

"How do you do?" is definitely an archaic greeting. In Jane Austen's novels, people did not only ask "How do you do?" but referred to it in the past tense in a way no one would today. For example in [Persuasion](http://pemberley.net/etext/Persuasion/chapter18.htm) (1817):

> She and the Harvilles came on Tuesday very safely, and in the evening we went to ask her how she did,

Back then, they didn't use continuous/progressive tenses, so they wouldn't say "How are you doing?" Nowadays we use the continuous form all the time, and we reinterpret this relic as "How are you doing?", or (more commonly to my UK ear) "How are you?". Hence, we reply "Fine, thanks. And you?" or similar.

Comment: I'm not sure your example proves that. "To ask her how she did" may be using past simple because it's indirect speech

Comment: *Back then, they didn't use continuous/progressive tenses,"  - I have difficulty accepting.that. "Robert Burns - Feb 2 1790 (letter)  - "What are you doing, and how are you doing? Have you lately seen any of my few friends?"

Answer (score 0):

I've heard three somewhat unusual responses to this question. You can take them seriously, or not.

My late uncle, who loved to be humorously sarcastic and throw people a bit of surprise would often respond, "You'd better watch out, because I might tell you."

My grandmother, a classy woman, would actually answer a bit about how she was feeling that day - "I have a headache and arthritis and constipation and .... " After listing her woes, it always ended with, "I'm healthy!"

An interesting short polite answer that I've been hearing lately is, "Thank G-d". I thought this was an answer that was unique to the Orthodox Jewish community. However, recently, I have been hearing this from a number of non-Jews, as well. I don't know if they learned this from the other community or this is part of their religious belief, or what. But, I think it's a nice response.

Why use a rather confusing and somwhat impolite answer? I would feel insulted if someone responded to my "How do you do" with another "how do you do". If you dont mean to ask people how they are doing, then hello, goodmorning, etc should suffice. 
The use of that must have been born out of pride, where some think its disrespectful to be greeted with such inquiry, so they respond with same.

Comment: You may feel insulted if someone responds to "How do you do?" by repeating it back, but historically the expression was a set greeting equivalent to "pleased to meet you" and/or "good morning", and the other person may feel that they are insulting you if they *don't* repeat it back.

Answer (score 0):

I generally reply “how do you do what?” just like Grumpy did: https://getyarn.io/yarn-clip/62a9dc6e-423f-46bb-b573-c2b1d53bae37