# What is the best answer to the question "How are you" in business meetings?

Tags: business-language, questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When someone asks, “How are you?”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/22320/when-someone-asks-how-are-you)

Every time when my colleges from USA ask me "How are you?" I don't know what should I answer. I think that answer like "Fine, thanks. What about you?" is not perfect. Could you provide patterns for such situation?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> Fine, thanks. What about you?

There's nothing wrong with your answer, although it might get tiresome if you word it exactly the same way, every time you're asked. But the solution for that is to merely use a few simple variations:

> I'm doing great today - and you?
>
> Doing well, thanks. How about you?
>
> Not bad, yourself?
>
> Thanks for asking, I'm doing fine.

I think it's usually best to avoid clever responses to such a standard question, particularly when you're with new acquaintences. Sure, you could reply with something like, "[I'm happy as a clam](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/happy+as+a+clam)," but that's not very professional, and it would probably undermine your credibility rather than enhance it. Such jocular ways of answering are best left said among close acquaintences when everyone is kidding around.

Comment: You can even just answer "Nice to see you" or the like. We understand that it's basically just a longer form of "hello" and they're not actually inquiring as to your condition.

Answer (score 6):

"Fine, thanks. Yourself?" is what I usually reply.

Comment: I think that it sounds not very friendly :)

Comment: @Warlock: you're welcome to your opinion, of course. But it's very common usage. "How are you?" is not usually an actual question, but more a substitute for "Hello". As such it doesn't require too much in the way of response. The friendliness (or lack thereof) is in the delivery.

Comment: I used to work with someone, who when asked "how are you?" would pause, consider for a few seconds, and then reply "Good!" with a tone that suggested he was quite touched that you had cared enough about his well-being as to ask. For most of us though, it's a formality more than anything more, and this answer, as with Barrie's, fit the bill fine.

Answer (score 4):

The answer given by dnagirl is one possibility. Another is 'I'm very well, thank you. How are you?'

Comment: Ok, thanks. Are there any famous phrases from books, musicals or cinema?

Comment: @Warlock. What sort of thing did you have in mind?

Comment: I mean, that you can show your erudition by answering with a famous  phrase. This approach is widely used in Russia when people answer questions with quotes from classical literature.

Comment: @Warlock. I'm afraid it would take more time and energy than I have available to find such a reference. In any case, what occurs in literature may not be relevant to what occurs in normal speech. Moreover, it isn't really necessary to undertake such a task. The everyday experience of native speakers is enough to provide an answer.

Comment: I had a friend who, when asked "How are you?" would often reply, "Just right." The reference, of course, is from _Goldilocks and the Three Bears_. That's hardly "classic literature" (unless you include children's literature). His answer was both optimistic and unique, but not so unusual as to be socially awkward. I don't think he'd mind if you borrowed it, so long as you are genuinely feeling quite content at the time. One reason it worked for him was his personality: he was inclined to be thankful for the blessings in life and to roll with the hardships. Best to be genuine when being clever.