# How do you do at work? How are you doing at school?

Tags: questions

I need to ask someone I know about the current state of that person's affairs at a particular sector of activity.

Mind you, I am not talking about a generic "hello". I've read through the [Do you really answer “How do you do?” with “How do you do?”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/16312/do-you-really-answer-how-do-you-do-with-how-do-you-do) and this is not what I am after.

I really mean to find out if there are any notable news/notifications about the person's doings. Either positive or negative.

Intuitively I would ask my daughter: "**How are you doing at school?**". But she is a child and is meant to treat all my questions seriously and answer properly i.e. not with "**fine, thanks**" but give me some details.

What about a situation when the asked person is of an equal social state and is not my subordinate? Does my question like: "**How are you doing at work?**" mean I need to know if there are actually any important news at person's work/business?

Comment: *What's new at work?*

Comment: @Drew Do you mean that saying `How are you doing as work?` does not have that?

Comment: No; I just suggested another way to ask.

Comment: Or you could say "How are things at work?"

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on [interpersonal.se].

Comment: Or, after the person says "Fine, thank you!", you could say: "So, how are you _really_ doing at work?"